# How can I cap the total space that mysql / mariadb binary logs take up?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I recently had my disk space completely filled with mysql binary log files (`mysql-bin.000123`, etc).

I was able to resolve short term by with `PURGE BINARY LOGS TO` (via [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/41054)).

To try and keep it from happening going forward I set lower limits on `expire_logs_days` and `max_binlog_size`. Yet, I'm still worried that a huge number of log files could be generated in a short period without a limit on the **total space** used by logs or the **total number of logs** allowed.

Is there something I'm missing? Or do I just need to keep setting `expire_logs_days` lower or turn off binary logging all together if it keeps being a problem?

**EDIT:**

I understand it's important to diagnose what's causing the logs to fill up quickly and solve that issue. This question is not about how to diagnose what's making them fill quickly, but rather - how do I safeguard against the disk filling to 100% and crashing the server in the case that something is setup wrong or an unexpected circumstance starts to fill these logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`max_binlog_size` has little effect on keeping disk space down; `expire_logs_days` is the one to worry about.

How fast are the logs filling up?

One way binlogs can fill up extremely fast is when you accidentally have the *same* `server_id` on multiple servers in a Replication setup.

Which version?  Which `binlog_format`?  Lots of multi-row `UPDATEs`/`DELETEs`?

**More**

`expire_logs_days` is the best available builtin tool.  There may be 3rd party monitoring tools (or you could write one) that watch for disk space.

In *any* system, you should have some kind of monitoring on disk space -- it is not just the binlog that can go berserk.  The "general log" and the slowlog can, also.  And your application can go berserk.  And so forth.

Comment: I understand that it's important to go into the logs and analyze why they are filling up fast when there is an issue. That's something I can do after an issue occurs. What I'm looking for is the best way to safeguard against mysql logs filling the entire disk and crashing the server. I don't want that to happen ever no matter what else is setup wrong. My concern is that `expire_logs_days` is  a cap on time, not on disk space.

Comment: Alas, no.  I added to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your all your help Rick. Good to know there is no built in setting for it. I do have disk space monitoring going. I was just hoping there might be something similar to logrotate where you can set a cap on the log size *and* then also on the total number of logs, for a net result that it's difficult to fill the entire disk with log results. Sounds like there is not (without a custom script).